# How do I cascade a delete from the many side of a unidirectional one-to-many in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I have the following unidirectional one to many relationship between two domain classes:

```
class Single {
    static hasMany = [ multiples: Multiple ]
}

class Multiple {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to cascade the delete from the `Multiple` class to the many relationship on `Single`?

What I have found that works is to add to add an `onDelete: Cascade` property to the FK that exists on the `multiple_id` column of the join table via the database script - however what I would really like to do is to express this in the GORM mapping DSL (and without creating a separate domain class to explicitly represent the join table). But there does not appear to be a way to manage relationships on the implicit join table of a uni one-to-many - unless I've missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to use bidirectional? If not, take a look at http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html?